# Regex for a decimal symbol , a percentage symbol and 0-9 for replace function in react

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-redux

```
handleCheck = (e)=> {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''); 
  }
```

This is the code now I am having .It allows only 0-9.

I want to modify this as that it accepts

- 0-9
- % symbol
- decimal point

  The input format is(0.00%)

Comment: does `/[^0-9.%]/g` work for you? (I'm not familiar with reactjs..)

Comment: Yes it works . only for accepting numbers

Comment: `.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')` won't remove any dot and you might get `5.........5` in the input. Try `.replace(/^([0-9]*\.)|[^0-9%]/g, '$1')`. Or `.replace(/^[^0-9.]*([0-9]*)(?:[^0-9]*(\.))?|[^0-9%]/g, '$1$2')`. Well, there will be a similar problem with `%`. So, probably a validation approach would be "cleaner".